# Meaning of exit code -1

Tags: python

I have a program runs in the Python programming environment (both Anaconda and PyCharm), but won't work outside of it. It works on my wife's laptop and my son's desktop, but not on my desktop. Why not? All three computers run the latest version of Windows 10. My computer has an i7-3700K CPU.

The program ends in PyCharm with the message: Process finished with exit code -1. What does this mean?

Here is the program:

```
from sympy import primefactors
print("\n\n\n\n")
print("\t\t Prime Factors")
print("\t\t ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \n")
number = int(input("\t\t Enter a number: "))
print("\n\t\t Prime factors", primefactors(number))
```

Here is the output screen:

```
     Prime Factors
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 

     Enter a number: 456

     Prime factors [2, 3, 19]
```

Process finished with exit code -1

Comment: This means that there was an error. Is there any error message? It should be in red and start with `Traceback (most recent call last):`

Comment: It runs ok. I get 'Process finished with exit code 0' I'm using PyCharm also, Python 3.7.1

Comment: Does the program run outside of the PyCharn environment. Would it run from your desktop, for example?

Comment: I ran it inside the ide. I have just tested it inside the terminal tab of PyCharm and got no error message. I would comment out the lines one by one from the bottom up and see if exit -1 disappears.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and then put everything back. The progam now returns exit code 0. However, it still will not run outside the programming environment.